# Styles import with parameters in HTML

Tags: css, hyperlink

Please, explain what does "**?v=1**" mean in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">?`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an informal way of versioning external resources, and of controlling whether they are cached.  You increment that number when the file changes, guaranteeing that all browsers load the new version.  The number isn't actually used anywhere - it's just a way of uniquifying the URL for the current version of the file.

Comment: I had not thought to use fake file extensions as variables. Well done.

Comment: Thanks, Richie! Now it makes sense for me. Is there anything else that can be written instead of **v=1**? Everytime when I try to read HTML code, I get confused with those after **?**. If there is a book on the web, please suggest me! Thanks!

Comment: You can put anything you like after the `?`, as long as it changes when the file changes.  Something like `?unique=1234` or `?version=1234` might make it easier to understand.  Or sometimes people use the file's timestamp: `?date=2013-06-19:12:55:01`.